# Why does Xfce sometimes not properly load the theme (Appearance) on login?

Tags: xubuntu, login, themes, xfce

Sometimes when I log in, Xfce (4.10, on Xubuntu-14.04) doesn't look right at all – the colour theme is an odd mixture of the correct settings (Xfce-darkness, in my case) and what's presumably the Xubuntu defaults.

[image: Xfce look after failed desktop-theme load]

This happens in an estimated 5% of all logins (with no apparent systematic relationship to parameters such as whether networking is available, recent updates, mains vs. battery power etc.). Sometimes the theme suddenly flips to the correct one a few seconds after the programs in the session are loaded, sometimes it doesn't happen at all.

If I log out and in once more, everything is right again.

[image: Xfce after re-login]

What could be the reason for this, and how can I force the correct theme to be loaded without switching to another theme and back, or logging out and in again?

Comment: +1 because I had similar experience, either in Xubuntu 12.04 or 14.04. I saw noticeable delays after login, before the theme is applied correctly or mixed. I don't experience this lately, but I wish to know the answer too.

Comment: I had this too from an installation that went all the LTS from 10.04 to 16.04. Reason was a crash of the xfce4 settings daemon. Was never reproducable on fresh installs, so maybe recreating the user may solve this.